# How do I edit PubNub Message and Add reaction to individual message

Tags: javascript, stream, storage, chat, pubnub

I have been working with PubNub, I tried storage and playback to update ( edit ) message, but failed. 
Kindly make me understand with code example, how to do it.

Comment: Can you share the code you used to attempt your edit? Which PubNub SDK and version did you use? Can you enable SDK logging and reproduce? If so, send that to [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com).

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide some examples of your code?
You can find the docs for storage and playback at: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference-storage-and-playback

1st thing you need to do is create a PubNub Client:

```
var pubnub = new PubNub({
    subscribeKey: "mySubscribeKey",
    publishKey: "myPublishKey",
    cipherKey: "myCipherKey",
    authKey: "myAuthKey",
    logVerbosity: true,
    uuid: "myUniqueUUID",
    ssl: true,
});
```

Then you can make a history call to a specific channel you want messages for:

```
pubnub.history(
    {
        channel: 'channel ID you want history for',
        count: 100, // how many items to fetch
        stringifiedTimeToken: true, // false is the default
    },
    function (status, response) {
        // handle status, response
    }
);
```

After that you can just load the JSON into your UI

Docs on editing a message: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/message-update-delete

To edit a message

> Using the Interleaving pattern, you publish new versions of the same message to the same channel just like normal publishes. The subsequent messages must use the same message_id as the original message...

Let me know if this helps!
Mathew

Comment: I already read the docs, but that code only creates a new message.
I used this technique 

https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/message-update-delete#:~:text=PubNub%20stores%20all%20messages%20per,of%20messages%20within%20the%20stream.

This doc is not helpful

Answer (score 1):

thanks I found the solution: just using pubnub.addMessageAction() and pubnub.removeMessageAction() like this:

```
pubnub.addMessageAction(
{
    channel: 'channel1'
    messageTimetoken: '15610547826970040',
    action: {
        type: 'reaction',
        value: 'smiley_face',
    },
},
function(status, response) {

});
```